# How do i center my logo and have my hamburger menu on the left on shopify debut theme

Tags: html, css, themes, shopify, liquid

Can anyone guide on how to edit my code of my debut theme? I only have a theme.css not .liquid I want my logo to be in the middle and the hamburger menu visible on the left side on desktop view. I can place logo in the middle from customizer but I need help editing my theme files to get the functionality of the hamburger menu. I can't find breakpoints in my css file.

I have tried solutions from similar questions and I can get the hamburger showing but no functionality if anyone has been able to get this working I would like to know the work around.

This is my current header.liquid file

This is how it looks now:

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: In new Shopify themes, they drop the support for `SCSS`, so you can't find files with `.css.liquid` into the newer theme. you need to check media queries for it.

Comment: Please share some code that shows what you have tried till now

Comment: @Onkar i only have the theme.css no theme.css.liquid i think theres no .liquid fo debut theme

Comment: @sonali i will share my header.liquid code

Comment: @sonali so i tried Find max-width: 749px and replace all the instance with max-width: 768px

Also replace:

min-width: 750px with min-width: 769px

which was suggested on a similar question but it doesnt make the hamburger visible on those break points.

Comment: you need to update the code into the header.liquid and CSS file to achieve the same https://prnt.sc/xox7em

Comment: @onkar thats exacly what im trying to do pls how did you do this

Comment: can you tell me what to update in my header.liquid and css files @Onkar

Comment: I think you try the Brooklyn theme from Shopify, they have a default behavior once the menu items are too long to adjust into one row. I think this is fast and good.https://brooklyn-theme-classic.myshopify.com/

Comment: @Onkar Thanks for helping out i only have 3 menus and ive customized my debut theme alot to change now. ill keep looking for another solution. appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: Okay, allow me sometime, I will provide you code.

Comment: @Onkar no rush if you have anything send here ill keep watching this thread. thansk again i really appreciate your help

Comment: Here is the gist link, where I have update liquid code and some CSS, you might add some extra CSS for desktop and mobile, according to your design. [demo](https://mydevshop-51.myshopify.com/) [Gist](https://gist.github.com/o-nkar/7d0adc0627be5ff7d3f6ae93f29ad370)

Comment: @Onkar Thanks a million you are a life saver lets

Comment: @Onkar do you mind explaining what you changed to make it visible

Comment: Okay, add a button to the left side and remove the from the right and display it for all devices, in past it visible for mobile devices, then hide the main menu with CSS and align-items for better display.

Comment: @Onkar hello sorry to bother you im having trouble centering the logo on mobile view with the hamburger when i inspect the page the hamburger width is too much but i cant see how to change it .

Comment: are able to share the URL of the page to check?

Comment: @Onkar no password. is it ok if i PM on github?